# Thread not ending possible that exceptions cause this?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm starting multiple threads that do different things.
The threads all have a "endme" boolean variable. Now when I try to end the threads by setting that variable and then end the debugger it screams that it could not end all processes.

After debugging a bit I found out that the processes go into the "ending" part of their code when the "end me" variable is set accordingly. but then an exception happens and is thrown.

Now my question is: Can it be that the exception causes a thread to not be able to be ended any longer?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the problem with program code when the code is absent or doesn't show the issue. Please, provide [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will describe your problem more precisely and reduce any further speculations about actual details. And even more - creating clean and short problem demo will improve your own understanding of both the issue and the whole program.

Comment: In this case as it is a general question if thrown exceptions are able to cause a thread to not be endable the question is what demo code should be given? (the calling method only or also the method of the called code that is executed in the thread)?

Comment: You need to show us example code that reproduces the problem.  It could be due to exceptions.  If so, enable catching all exceptions when thrown in Visual Studio to find out.  Or it could be you need to use [`Volatile.Write()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712815%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Volatile.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Or it could be something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting my comment to an answer since it is correct and might even be relevant.

In the absence of any code to reproduce the problem, I will note that if you are communicating between threads by setting a boolean variable "endMe", then you need to use volatile [reads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712942%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [writes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712815%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access that variable, for instance (in .Net 4.5):

```
public class ThreadedWorker
{
    bool endMe = false;

    public bool EndSignalled { get { return Volatile.Read(ref endMe); } }

    public void SignalEnd()
    {
        Volatile.Write(ref isEnded, true);
    }
}
```

Or in all c# versions you can use the [`volatile`](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/12/04/sayonara-volatile/) [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx)

```
public class ThreadedWorker
{
    volatile bool endMe = false;

    public bool EndSignalled { get { return endMe; } }

    public void SignalEnd()
    {
        endMe = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to put a call to `System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();` before the access to `endMe` rather than making it volatile.